# Delphi 2009 command line compiler using dcc32.cfg?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

In Delphi 2009, how can I build a project using command line.  I tried using the command line compiler and supplying -a -u -i -r in dcc32.cfg file.  But compiler is not recognizing the paths and throwing the error required package xyzPack is not found.

```
    -aWinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE
    -u"C:\MyProj\Output\DCP"
    -i"C:\MyProj\Output\DCP"
    -r"C:\MyProj\Output\DCP"
```

and on command line i execute the command :

```
    dcc32 "C:\MyProj\MyProject.dpr" -B -E"c:\MyProj\Output\EXE"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks & Regards,
Pavan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of invoking the compiler directly, consider using MSBuild on your .dproj, since that's what the IDE uses. [Delphi MSBuild Build Configurations From Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558147/delphi-msbuild-build-configuraions-from-command-line) might help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

From the related answer (as shown below) ie:

[Compiling with Delphi 2009 from a command line under Windows Vista 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006831/compiling-with-delphi-2009-from-a-command-line-under-windows-vista-64-bit)

I notice that you should be able to build a single package from the command line this way. I have used batch files (buildall.cmd) to launch dcc32, and have not yet used msbuild.

I have ultimately found both approaches frustrating, and have instead decided to opt for building a little GUI shell (a lite version of Final Builder, if you like) that basically works as a semi-graphical semi-command-line way of automating my builds and filtering the compiler output to produce results.  I would be highly interested in anyone else's experiences with "tinder box" (daily or even continuous build) operations with Delphi.

You may end up where I'm heading... just buy Final Builder. :-)